# what does the numpy operation "()[]" mean?

Tags: python, numpy-ndarray

```
l_mask = (1.0 - np.clip(20 * (l - 0.05), 0, 1))[None, ...]
```

what is the meaning of the "()[None,...]", and why should we code like this

Comment: The lone `None` inserts an extra axis (dimension) into your array. So if you have a 2D array, this would make it 3D, with the first axis having size 1. The ellipses indicate the remaining axies. The parentheses in your question are just grouping parentheses, similarly to `(2 + 3) x 4`.

Comment: Thank you. I have understood the None

Answer (score 0):

`[None,..]` adds an axis or dimension to an array. `m_[:, None]` puts together each element of `m_`  in an array.

This is also called `newaxis`, which is an object can be used in all slicing operations to create an axis of length one. This is also used in place of this with the same result [[1]](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html#numpy.newaxis).

For example:

```
import numpy as np;
```

```
a = np.array([[a,b],[c,d]])
```

then,
`a[:,None]` is the same as `np.array([[[a, b]], [[c, d]]])`.

You can check out this documentation for reference:
https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html#numpy.newaxis

Comment: Thank you for replying. I will check out the reference.

Answer (score -1):

The syntax is used to slice ndarrays.

x[(exp1, exp2, ..., expN)] is equivalent to x[exp1, exp2, ..., expN]

Remember that a slicing tuple can always be constructed as obj and used in the x[obj] notation. Slice objects can be used in the construction in place of the **[start:stop:step]** notation. For example, **x[1:10:5,::-1] can also be implemented as obj = (slice(1,10,5), slice(None,None,-1))**; x[obj] . This can be useful for constructing generic code that works on arrays of arbitrary dimensions.

For better understating in your case try the below:

```
(1.0 - np.clip(20 * (l - 0.05), 0, 1))[None,:]

(1.0 - np.clip(20 * (l - 0.05), 0, 1))[:,None]

(1.0 - np.clip(20 * (l - 0.05), 0, 1))[None,None,-1]
```

Comment: This doesn't explain the single `None`.